NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary
Running a Java sample file under Eclipse in a Maven project using libsdl4j-2.28.4-1.6. Getting a NoClassDefFoundError.
Here is the error stack :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary
    at io.github.libsdl4j.jna.SdlNativeLibraryLoader.loadLibSDL2(SdlNativeLibraryLoader.java:33)
    at io.github.libsdl4j.jna.SdlNativeLibraryLoader.registerNativeMethods(SdlNativeLibraryLoader.java:24)
    at io.github.libsdl4j.api.Sdl$InternalNativeFunctions.<clinit>(Sdl.java:56)
    at io.github.libsdl4j.api.Sdl.SDL_Init(Sdl.java:30)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)

Here is the SdlNativeLibraryLoader class :
package io.github.libsdl4j.jna;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;

import static com.sun.jna.Library.OPTION_CLASSLOADER;
import static com.sun.jna.Library.OPTION_STRING_ENCODING;

public final class SdlNativeLibraryLoader {

    public static final String SDL_LIBRARY_NAME = "SDL2";

    // This field keeps the reference to the loaded JNA library object to prevent it from being garbage collected.
    private static NativeLibrary libSDL2;

    private SdlNativeLibraryLoader() {
    }

    public static synchronized void registerNativeMethods(Class<?> nativeClass) {
        if (libSDL2 == null) {
            libSDL2 = loadLibSDL2();
        }
        Native.register(nativeClass, libSDL2);
    }

    private static NativeLibrary loadLibSDL2() {
        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
        options.put(OPTION_STRING_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        options.put(OPTION_CLASSLOADER, SdlNativeLibraryLoader.class.getClassLoader());
        return NativeLibrary.getInstance(SDL_LIBRARY_NAME, options);
    }

    public static <T extends Library> T loadLibSDL2InterfaceInstance(Class<T> libraryInterface) {
        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
        options.put(OPTION_STRING_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        options.put(OPTION_CLASSLOADER, SdlNativeLibraryLoader.class.getClassLoader());
        return Native.load(SDL_LIBRARY_NAME, libraryInterface, options);
    }
}

The process failed on method "NativeLibrary.getInstance".
Since it is a Maven project, I assume it is using the Maven Project Builder tool. However, in the properties, both the Java Builder (Eclipse) and the Maven Project Builder are activated. I tried without the Java Builder and obtained the same problem.  Here is the POM.xml :
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SDL4JDemo</groupId>
  <artifactId>JavaDemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-INSTALL{guice.disable.misplaced.annotation.check}</version>
  <name>Demo</name>
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
  </build>
</project>

In the target library of the project, I also have a "libsdl4j-2.28.4-1.6.pom" file :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.github.libsdl4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>libsdl4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.28.4-1.6</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>LibSDL4J</name>
    <description>LibSDL4J - Java language bindings for SDL2.</description>
    <url>https://libsdl4j.github.io/</url>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>zlib License</name>
            <url>https://opensource.org/licenses/Zlib</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Kamil Ševeček</name>
            <url>https://github.com/shinedeveloper</url>
            <email>libsdl4j@outlook.com</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/libsdl4j/libsdl4j.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://github.com:libsdl4j/libsdl4j.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/libsdl4j/libsdl4j/tree/master</url>
    </scm>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.36</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>

Found similar problem in litterature :

have deleted the "module-info.java" files; did not fix the problem
other problems found refer to com.sun.java.Library but not NativeLibrary or have different environment.

It looks like a library reference problem, but i cannot find what library is missing and how to add it in the dependencies.

Have you tried declaring your dependency on that io.github.libsdl4j artifact in your own pom file?

No. How do I do that ?

At https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jna/jna, it says that NativeLibrary has been moved from "com.sun.jna" to "net.java.dev.jna". How can I overide this reference in my project ?
